# Multiprocessing KeyboardInterrupt handling

Tags: python, multiprocessing

This problem seems to have been eluding me - all the solutions are more like workarounds and add quite a bit of complexity to the code.
Since its been a good while since any posts regarding this have been made, are there any `simple` solutions to the following - upon detecting a keyboard interrupt, cleanly exit all the childs proceses, terminate the program?

Code below is snippet of my multiproccess structure - I'd like to preserve as much as posible, while adding the needed functionality:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def multiprocess_init(l):
    global lock
    lock = l

def synchronous_print(i):
    with lock:
        print i
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    lock = Lock()
    pool = Pool(processes=5, initializer=multiprocess_init, initargs=(lock, ))

    for i in range(1,20):
        pool.map_async(synchronous_print, [i])

    pool.close() #necessary to prevent zombies
    pool.join() #wait for all processes to finish
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is to move to python 3. Python 2 has multiple problems with thread/process synchronization that have been fixed in python 3.

In your case, `multiprocessing` will doggedly recreate your child processes every time you send keyboard interrupt and `pool.close` will get stuck and never exit. You can reduce the problem by explicitly exiting the child process with `os.exit` and by waiting for individual results from `apply_async` so that you don't get stuck in `pool.close` prison.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Lock
import time
import os

def multiprocess_init(l):
    global lock
    lock = l
    print("initialized child")

def synchronous_print(i):
    try:
        with lock:
            print i
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("exit child")
        os.exit(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    lock = Lock()
    pool = Pool(processes=5, initializer=multiprocess_init, initargs=(lock, ))

    results = []
    for i in range(1,20):
        results.append(pool.map_async(synchronous_print, [i]))

    for result in results:
        print('wait result')
        result.wait()

    pool.close() #necessary to prevent zombies
    pool.join() #wait for all processes to finish
    print("Join completes")
```